# Is it possible to have round-robin DNS with /etc/hosts file?

Tags: hosts-file, domain-name-system, round-robin

Is it possible to have round-robin DNS with the follwing configuration in `/etc/hosts`?

```
192.168.4.10 shaakunthala.local
192.168.4.20 shaakunthala.local
```

I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 10):

[dnsmasq](http://dnsmasq.org/) inludes Round-robin DNS out-of-the-box

```
> egrep -m1 '^nameserver' /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
> grep -i rrtest /etc/hosts
1.1.1.1 rrtest
2.2.2.2 rrtest
> /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart 
Shutting down dnsmasq:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting dnsmasq:                                          [  OK  ]
> nslookup rrtest 
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   rrtest
Address: 2.2.2.2
Name:   rrtest
Address: 1.1.1.1

> nslookup rrtest 
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   rrtest
Address: 1.1.1.1
Name:   rrtest
Address: 2.2.2.2
```

Comment: dnsmasq can only archive wildcard dns or RR dns. You could use bind9 if you need the both features.

Answer (score 9):

No, that doesn't work.

Also /etc/hosts is a primitive form of name->address mapping that DNS is meant to replace. If you want round-robin DNS, install a DNS server.